Most Efficient And Convenient Way To Implement Matrices
i was thinking about the way to make matrices in C, that ensures matrix types (Matrix2x2, Matrix3x3, ...) and provides operations (Add, Substract, Multiply, Transpose). I found two methods.
First Method
I thought of implementing matrices as macros that construct arrays depending on the number of rows and columns.
I also made macros for constructing operations.
#define MATRIX_DEFINE(ROWS, COLUMNS) typedef float Matrix##ROWS##x##COLUMNS##[ROWS][COLUMNS]

MATRIX_DEFINE(2, 2);
MATRIX_DEFINE(3, 3);
MATRIX_DEFINE(4, 4);

#define MATRIX_ADD(ROWS, COLUMNS) ...
#define MATRIX_SUBSTRACT(ROWS, COLUMNS) ...
#define MATRIX_MULTIPLY(R1, C1, R2, C2) ...
#define MATRIX_TRANSPOSE(ROWS, COLUMNS) ...

I found that this method gives me more control and offers a more explicit way of operations.
I Also heard that hard-coding operations is more efficient that using dynamic memory allocation (Hence the use of macros).
Second Method
This is the dynamic approach and it goes as follows:
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double **data;
} Matrix;

Matrix createMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = rows;
    matrix.cols = cols;
    matrix.data = (double **)malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix.data[i] = (double *)malloc(cols * sizeof(double));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void freeMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        free(matrix.data[i]);
    }
    free(matrix.data);
}

Matrix multiplyMatrices(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    if (a.cols != b.rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Matrix dimensions do not match for multiplication\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Matrix result = createMatrix(a.rows, b.cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.cols; j++) {
            result.data[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++) {
                result.data[i][j] += a.data[i][k] * b.data[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

...

I don't know which approach i should go with and i would love some advice from you.

If your code is working, you should probably ask for a code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - One optimization would be to only make one allocation for the whole matrix instead of rows + 1 allocations.

Here is an alternative approach that handles dynamic dimensions and packed allocation:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    size_t len;
    double *data;
} Matrix;

#define MATRIX_CELL(m,i,j)  ((m).data[(i) * (m).cols + (j)])

Matrix createMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = rows;
    matrix.cols = cols;
    matrix.len = (size_t)cols * (size_t)rows;
    matrix.data = calloc(matrix.len, sizeof(*matrix.data));
    return matrix;
}

void freeMatrix(Matrix *mp) {
    if (mp) {
        free(mp->data);
        mp->data = NULL;
    }
}

Matrix addMatrices(const Matrix a, const Matrix b) {
    if (a.cols != b.cols || a.rows != b.rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Matrix dimensions do not match for addition\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Matrix result = createMatrix(a.rows, a.cols);
    if (result.data) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.len; i++)
            result.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
    }
    return result;
}

Matrix multiplyMatrices(const Matrix a, const Matrix b) {
    if (a.cols != b.rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Matrix dimensions do not match for multiplication\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Matrix result = createMatrix(a.rows, b.cols);
    if (result.data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.cols; j++) {
                double res = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++) {
                    res += MATRIX_CELL(a, i, k) * MATRIX_CELL(b, k, j);
                }
                MATRIX_CELL(result, i, j) = res;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Compilers are very efficient at optimizing the above code to avoid most multiplications for cell addressing.

I think it would be safer if freeMatrix got matrix by pointer, and after freeing set matrix->data to null (and rows and cols to 0). Otherwise it's easy to make a mistake like using a matrix after it was freed.

@wohlstad: good point. Answer amended.  As a general rule, passing the matrix by value is OK only if the matrix is not modified.  Returning the matrix by value can easily cause hard to find memory leaks.

@GameSlayerLLC: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
